# array keep return empty [swift}

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a function, and array, i try to save the xml data into the array, but it return empty set when i print out. why is it?

```
func populateCountries() {


    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://api.jocom.com.my/feed", parameters: ["req" : "country"])

        .responseData { response in


            let getCountriesXML = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)


            for elem in getCountriesXML["rss"]["channel"]["item"] {

               //var countriesArray = [String]() which i declare outside of the function.
                self.countriesArray.append(elem["name"].element!.text!)


            }



    }

    print(self.countriesArray)
    print(self.countriesArray.count)
}
```

Comment: what you get when you print `elem`?

Comment: You should read the "Response Handling" part in the Alamofire README: "Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously..." . This has been asked and answered repeatedly.

Comment: You don't seem to be looking to see if the request succeeded or failed in the completion handler

Comment: it return the xml data that i wanted to save in an array. Sorry, but im very new in SWift

Comment: @vicky As @martin-r says "Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously". This means that when you call `Alamofire.request` you can not expect it to answer straight away, it has to fetch data via the network first (which can take some time). Therefore, when you say `print(self.countriesArray)` straight after calling `Alamofire.request`, your `countriesArray` has not been populated yet, that only happens once the `request` call returns with data in the callback. Armed with that knowledge you should go and read the answer that @martin-r has provided you with :)

Comment: @pbodsk so what should i do?

Comment: @vicky As @martin-r says: "read the "Response Handling" part of the Alamofire README" :)  You can find it here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire Your problem is that you are trying to print the contents of `countriesArray` "too early". It hasn't been filled by Alamofire yet, that happens in your callback method. Try moving the print inside your callback, right after the `for elem` loop and I'm sure you'll see that your `countriesArray` has been populated as expected.

Comment: You can also search for "return value from asynchronous function" to find similar question with solutions.